# How to extract values from a text string using a number as delimiter?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I have a bit of a unique situation, I have a column of data that has text values:

```
Column

sdfsadf42lkjdflk
skld35kdfosdffj
kdfjsi78ldsfjoi
```

Result should look like:

```
Column

42lkjdflk
35kdfosdffj
78ldsfjoi
```

Is there a way to cut out everything before a number? A generalized way would be nice in the event that number currently not included can still be evaluated for (the instance of a number always being used is the only constant)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your column is named **ColumnName**, in powerquery, add custom column with formula

```
= Text.RemoveRange([ColumnName], 0, Text.PositionOfAny([ColumnName],{"0".."9"}))
```

Comment: I will try this out!

Comment: it works fine as shown assuming your column is named **ColumnName**

Answer (score 2):

You can try finding the index and then slicing the str using the same index. I will show you with an example.

```
var str = "skld35kdfosdffj";
var firstDigit = str.search(/\d/);
str = str.slice(firstDigit,str.length);
console.log(str);
```